# Class exists but says "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, terminal, jar, macos-big-sur, zshrc

I'm trying to compile and run a basic hello word java program on macOS terminal, It's successfully compiling but when I run it, it says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main`. It was working before but suddenly stopped working.

**Hello.java**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

**~/.zshrc**

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$PWD/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/opt/openjdk/plugins/javax.mail.jar
```

**terminal**

```
arghadip@Mac % rm *.class; ls; javac Hello.java; ls; java Main;
Hello.java
Hello.java  Main.class
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
arghadip@Mac %
```

I've installed java with `brew install java`. What went wrong?

Comment: is the name of the file that contains the `Main` class really `program.java`?

Comment: check updated question

Comment: add `:.` to end of CLASSPATH (unless your `Main.class` is inside of one of the listed `.jar`)

Comment: yes Sir!  `export CLASSPATH=$PWD/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/opt/openjdk/plugins/javax.mail.jar:.`

Comment: I've change my class name from `Main` > `ThisIsMyPersonalClass` and added `:.` at the end of the `CLASSPATH`. and updated my source. It worked. but what does that `:.` mean sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to run the `Main.class`

just do: `java Hello.java`

Comment: but I want to compile then run it.

Comment: @Arghadip In recent versions of Java, `java Hello.java` will both compile and run a simple class.  By the way, you might enjoy the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) tool for Java, [*jshell*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell).